# How to process all files in a folder with python code

Tags: process, python, wildcards

I have the following code in python:

```python
#/usr/bin/python

from Bio import SeqIO

count = SeqIO.convert(“genome1.gbk”, “genbank”, “genome1.fasta”, “fasta”)

print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

This code converts the genbank file "genome1.gbk" to a fasta file "genome1.fasta". But now I want to convert all files in the current folder with this code. All the files in the current folder are genbank files and I want them to turn into fasta files with this code. I was thinking of using wildcards, but I don't know exactly how to change this code. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are there **nested** folders with files?

Comment: Nope, only genbank files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python's [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) feature:

```
#/usr/bin/python

from Bio import SeqIO
from os import scandir

with scandir() as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith('.gbk') and entry.is_file():
            count = SeqIO.convert(entry.name, 'genbank', '{}.fasta'.format(entry.name[:-4]), 'fasta')
            print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

Comment: it worked wonderfully !!

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this code:

```
import os 
from Bio import SeqIO

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  if filename.endswith(".gbk"):
    count = SeqIO.convert(filename, “genbank”, "{}.fasta".format(entry.name[:-4]), “fasta”)
    print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

BR,
Shahar

Comment: But in this case, all the outputs would have the same name (genome1.fasta) I'm right?. This code overwrite the output files with the same name and I don't want that. All the output files must have the same input names, but instead .gbk it must be .fasta

Comment: OK, got it, fixed my answer